# Copy Code from Jupyter Notebook with syntax highlighting (formatting, coloring) when pasting to Word

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I work with Jupyter Notebook and wont to make my own notes with code snippets in office word.
I want to have code pasted to word to be with syntax coloring, like it is on notebook, see here example:

[image: Sample_Code]

But when I paste to word, it plain text, and there is no way to paste formatted text.
This works well when working with some IDE for example, like IntelliJ.

Do someone know a way? Probably so extension? **I dont want to put code to IntelliJ first and then in Word** :)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't want to paste it into an IDE/Text editor, I would suggest using Visual Studio Code to run your notebook. Visual Studio Code has, if you download the Microsoft Python Extension, full support for Jupyter Notebook (Along with Intellisense), and if you open/run the notebook from within Visual Studio Code, type the code in and run it and copy the code, it will have the syntax copied as well, given that you have the `Editor: Copy With Syntax Highlighting` setting checked. I know that you were not wanting to copy the code into an IDE/Text editor, but running the notebook inside Visual Studio Code would be useful, as it does everything that opening it in your browser does- Run python, render Markdown, and it will copy with syntax highlighting (As well as, like I've already said, give you full usage of Visual Studio Code's Python extension).